# an error occurred submitting the answer stackoverflow

Tags: support, bug, answers, error-message, special-characters

[image: This is the exact code whats wrong here][image]

Am getting this error "an error occurred submitting the answer" in stackoverflow

Even here i couldn't add the code its showing the same error message!!

Comment: I have added my exact code as picture whats wrong in that?

Comment: That's what the duplicate explains.  It's likely a firewall on your end that's blocking the submission of the SQL statements.

Comment: It seems like you have been able to submit answers with code like that in the past.  I don't know enough T-SQL to tell what the firewall would be picking up as nefarious, though.

Comment: @jonsca yeah that is my concern i was able answer with some similar sql codes previously!!